# Error :string indices must be Integer , while sending data to sqlite database from Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, treeview

1. I'm trying to delete data by selecting it in, treeview then using

   `print("called deletefile FUNCTION !")`

   `selecteditem = treev2.item(treev2.focus())`

   `print(selecteditem)`
   #returns {'text': '', 'image': '', 'values': ['file1-1.txt', 'Dummy Data', '1-1', 'this is file1-1', 'txt', 'user1'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
2. so then I tried ,

`print(selecteditem['values'][1])`
returns Dummy Data

similarly `selecteditem['values'][0] selecteditem['values'][1] selecteditem['values'][2] ,..till [5]` etc

returns 'file1-1.txt', 'Dummy Data', '1-1', 'this is file1-1', 'txt', 'user1'

3. But when i put this values in sqlite query i get Error

```
mycodecur.execute(''' delete from Files where FileName=(?) and MadeBy=(?) '''[selecteditem['values'][0],selecteditem['values'][5]])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

4. tried again

```
mycodecur.execute(''' delete from Files where FileName=? and MadeBy=? '''[selecteditem['values'][0],selecteditem['values'][5]])
```

same error, literally everything is global

Here is link to mycode
[file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-7VWgbxuioC5UtifAESR8bitk8lfkzPm?usp=sharing)

Comment: Missing comma: `... MadeBy=(?) '''[selecteditem...]` should be `... MadeBy=(?) ''', [selecteditem...]`.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem !

Answer (score 0):

*As the user **acw1668** commented :*

I was **missing comma** after query.